# can i use NSStrings in alerts in iphone objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, alerts

I am trying to make an app where the user clicks a button and an alert pops up with the text from a textfield in it. But whenever i try, i just get a blank alert. This is my code:

```
@synthesize label;

@synthesize textBox1;

@synthesize text;

- (IBAction)buttonClick {
 UIAlertView *someText = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Text from textbox1" message: text delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
 [someText show];
 [someText release];
 text = textBox1.text;
 label.text = text;
}
```

what am i doing wrong it seems like everything is in place like it should be. I think the answer might have something to do with NSLog().

Comment: You're setting `text` *after* you display the UIAlertView. You need to set it before.

Comment: Also, `NSLog` will not magically make it work.

Answer (score 6):

You're setting the `text` property *after* you show the alert. When the alert is created, it's probably set to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare the variable test before the UIAlertView.

```
text = textBox1.text;
UIAlertView *someText = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Text from Textbox1" message:text delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[someText show];
```

Then you get the text from the textBox in your alert